# Why does command "git merge upstream/integration integration" opens nano editor?

Tags: git, github

It happens some time that when I run above mentioned command nano editor is opened and this is not always the case. Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. 
I wonder what is the need to open editor while merging ?

Comment: Probably merge is not fast-forward and editor pops up to give you a chance of modifying commit message

Comment: Is there anything in the editor?  Or is it just a blank editor window?

Answer (score 1):

If a merge can be done using a fast-forward, then git simply moves the HEAD and branch pointer forward to the new tip. No editor is required because no commit is generated.

In a merge situation where fast-forward is not possible, a merge commit is created, so git opens your editor to allow you to edit the commit message.